# Change Color of QgsMapToolEmitPoint

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have built a QGIS Plugin which activates the `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` for getting XY-Coords when I click on the map. Everything works as desired with the following code:

```
def foo(tool):
    click = (tool.x(), tool.y())
    do something ....

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
tool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)
tool.setCursor(Qt.SizeAllCursor)
tool.canvasClicked.connect(foo)
canvas.setMapTool(tool)
```

But there is a little problem left: When i have an activated Rasterlayer, styled as greyscale, sometimes it's hard to see where the Cross of the MapTool is. I just found how to change the Cursor from Cross to different Cursor Shapes from https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#CursorShape-enum

So I have the following question: Is there a possibility to change the color of the MapTool e.g. to red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know it's possible to change cursor color, but you can make your own cursor from an image file.

```
cursor = QCursor(QPixmap("C:/cursor.png"))
tool.setCursor(cursor)
```